# [TortoiseSVN error]The XML response contains invalid XML and Malformed XML: no element found

Tags: tortoisesvn

Can not check out remote repository to my PC.
I have check the URL I have used,
It is like

```
https//219.101.XXX.XXX/svn/Projectnane/doc/branches/phasename/
```

and I guess there is nothing wrong with the auth problem.

Because I can use the TortoiseSVN repository broswer to view the URL above,
and all the subfolders are "well" displayed in the list pane of the repository browser.
But when I click on the subfolders in the repository broswer,
"TortoiseSVN error The XML response contains invalid XML and Malformed XML: no element found"
was displayed in the detail pane of repository broswer.

Same problem will happen when I directly check out the URL listed above,
and same error message is displayed.I guess I need some help.

**Additional Info**

- a proxy server is used.
- a vpn is running.
- TortoiseSVN version:1.9.7
- Unable to access the SVN server due to security problems.

Comment: What do you get when you load that same URL in a regular browser (Firefox, Chrome...)?

Comment: Everything works fine when I load the same URL in a regular browser.
Chrome OK.
IE11 OK.
(For some reason I can not use Firefox in this PC.)

Comment: I presume you've already configured the proxy in TortoiseSVN or you wouldn't see any URL. Sorry, I don't know what it can be.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes,I configured the proxy in TortoiseSVN,otherwise I can not see any URL in TortoiseSVN. I can’t figure it out either .However,thank you for your reply!